# Flurl: Call failed with status code 308 (Permanent Redirect) but no AutoRedirect

Tags: flurl

I am using Flurl to make REST API calls. I am stumbling on an exception HttpStatusCode 308 because it will not cause an automatic redirect.

```
`var url = kundenServiceUrl
                .AppendPathSegment("kunde")
                .AppendPathSegment(kundeNr)
                .WithHeaders(new
                {
                    accept = "application/json", ...


                })
                .WithOAuthBearerToken(xxx);
```

await url... creates an Exception "Call failed with status code 308 (Permanent Redirect)"
The REST API documentation says that 308 is generated when the "kundeNr" is a doublet and redirect to the new "kundeNr".

.AllowHttpStatus("308") suppress the exception but I can't get any information about the redirect (no location header in url.headers).

How I can achieve the automatic redirect? (In Postman it works fine)

Answer (score 0):

308 should auto-redirect by default. A couple things to check:

1. Is it trying to go from secure to insecure (https to http)? That won't auto-redirect.
2. Any chance it's caught up in a redirect loop? That'll [short-circuit](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclienthandler.maxautomaticredirections) at 50 by default. (I doubt it if it works in Postman.)
3. Are you providing your own `HttpClient` or `HttpMessageHandler` to Flurl via a custom [factory](https://flurl.dev/docs/configuration/#httpclientfactory)? Make sure you're using an `HttpClientHandler` with `AllowAutoRedirect` set to `true`.

If it's none of those I'm a little stumped. I will say that at least the exception behavior will change a bit in 3.0. In 2.x, Flurl throws whenever [`IsSuccessStatusCode`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.web.http.httpresponsemessage.issuccessstatuscode) is false, meaning anything outside of 2xx. 3.0 will only throw for >= 400, so disabled redirects won't throw. There's also some [fancy new features](https://github.com/tmenier/Flurl/issues/500) related to redirects coming soon that'll give you greater control, so even though I can't explain what happened here if none of the 3 situations above applies, you should be able to force the matter. Follow that GitHub issue to be notified when that is released (or just follow [@FlurlHttp](https://twitter.com/flurlhttp) on Twitter).

Comment: Triple no to your points, sadly. When I change the setting in Postman to Automatically follow redirects to OFF, it's the same behavoiur like flurl (Status 308). Setting it to ON gets 200.

Comment: Try it with a raw HttpClient instead of Flurl.